# Derivation of metric from product topology?

Tags: metric-spaces, differential-topology

Suppose you have two topological spaces, g11 and g22, which are "components" of a more general topology. For example, suppose that a metric has components g11, g12, g21, and g22. And suppose you want to find a new metric which describes the g11 × g22 topology (the Cartesian product of g11 and g12). How would you find a metric that describes the new g11 × g22 topology?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ metrizable?

Comment: In what way is the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ related to the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, A and B are metrizable.

Comment: @basket: Thank You, I've made the question  much more specific, in a way that I hope answers  your question.

Comment: It was a hint not a question! How is the metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ constructed from the metrics on $\mathbb{R}$? How do we generalize this?

Answer (score 1):

The [product metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_metric) construction is the standard method of putting a metric on a product of metric spaces.

If $A$ and $B$ are not equipped with a metric to start with, you would need to verify metrizability first. The [Nagata-Smirnov metrization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata%E2%80%93Smirnov_metrization_theorem) gives necessary and sufficient conditions for metrizability.